# How to extract creation date from a remote url picture?

Tags: perl, image-processing, scrapy

If I have a link of a picture like that:

```
http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png
```

Can I retrieve the original creation date of this picture without downloading it? Actually **I tried downloading it** with [Image::Grab](http://search.cpan.org/~mahex/Image-Grab-1.4.2/) but I get my 'local allocation time' instead the original. The same using ctime(stat) way.

Can anyone tell me if it's possible to do? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTTP resources are not files.

No, without downloading you can only inspect the [Last-Modified HTTP header](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.29):

```
use LWP::UserAgent qw();
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $res = $ua->head('http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png');
print $res->header('Last-Modified'); # 'Mon, 02 Apr 2012 02:13:37 GMT'
```

Sometimes images contain metadata, but you must download to inspect.

```
use LWP::UserAgent qw();
use Image::ExifTool qw(ImageInfo);
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->mirror('http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png', 'logo3w.png');
print ImageInfo('logo3w.png')->{CreateDate}; # undef
```

Comment: Thanks @daxim, I had some misunderstood concepts... I think 'Last Modified' in header info can do the job :-)